# Deducting values from 2 case statements from one another

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have two CASE statements and I'm trying to deduct the value of one from another, but I can't get the code to work. Does anyone have any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

The 2 CASE statements are:

```
case
    when "D570M"."END_DATE" IS NULL then TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')))
    when "D570M"."END_DATE" > (LAST_DAY(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'DD-MON-YYYY'))) then TO_CHAR (LAST_DAY(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')))
    else TO_CHAR("D570M"."END_DATE", 'DD-MON-YYYY')
end as "END DATE",
```

and

```
case
    when "D570M"."START_DATE"> LAST_DAY(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')) then TO_CHAR((LAST_DAY(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'DD-MON-YYYY'))), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
    else TO_CHAR("D570M"."START_DATE", 'DD-MON-YYYY')
end as "START DATE",
```

When I try to combine these I get errors (missing right parenthesis). The combined code is:

```
SUM(
    (
        case
            when "D570M"."END_DATE" IS NULL then TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')))
            when "D570M"."END_DATE" > (LAST_DAY(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'DD-MON-YYYY'))) then TO_CHAR (LAST_DAY(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')))
            else TO_CHAR("D570M"."END_DATE", 'DD-MON-YYYY')
        end as "END DATE"
    ) -
    (
        case
            when "D570M"."START_DATE"> LAST_DAY(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')) then TO_CHAR((LAST_DAY(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'DD-MON-YYYY'))), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
            else TO_CHAR("D570M"."START_DATE", 'DD-MON-YYYY')
        end as "START DATE")
    )
```

as "CALENDAR DAYS",

Comment: Remove the aliases: `as "END DATE"` and `as "START DATE"`

Comment: can you provide the full sql statement? it would be much easier to find the grammatical error.

Comment: There is no need to double-quote all the Oracle identifiers - e.g. `case
    when D570M.END_DATE IS NULL then`.  Double-quoting is only needed in the exceptional case that the identifier contains lowercase letters or special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forpas is right about the aliases; you also want to remove all those TO_CHAR() calls. You want to be doing arithmetic with dates, not with strings of characters. I think you're trying to remove the time portion of the date, and the function you want for that is `TRUNC()`.

```
-- example data
with D570M as (select sysdate-60 as start_date, sysdate as end_date from dual)
-- query
select
        case
            when D570M.END_DATE IS NULL then TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1)))
            when D570M.END_DATE > TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1))) then TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1)))
            else TRUNC(D570M.END_DATE)
        end as "END DATE",
        case
            when D570M.START_DATE> TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1))) then TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1)))
            else TRUNC(D570M.START_DATE)
        end as "START DATE",
SUM(
    (
        case
            when D570M.END_DATE IS NULL then TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1)))
            when D570M.END_DATE > TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1))) then TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1)))
            else TRUNC(D570M.END_DATE)
        end
    ) -
    (
        case
            when D570M.START_DATE > TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1))) then TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1)))
            else TRUNC(D570M.START_DATE)
        end
    )) as "CALENDAR DAYS"
from d570m;
```

Output:

```
END DATE  START DATE CALENDAR DAYS
--------- ---------- -------------
31-DEC-19 08-NOV-19             53
1 row selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, they have worked perfectly for me! The double quotes were added automatically into the code so I'll remove them.